# Arabic support for Android Emulator (API Level 2.2)

Tags: android, emulation

I am developing an application that supports localization and want to add Arabic to the emulator (it has only English, French, Dutch, ...)
 Anyone know how I can add Arabic so the whole emulator runs in Arabic??

**Using API Level 2.2**

Answer (score 2):

Although v2.2 was supposed to add better support for various languages which don't use the 'Latin' char-set (such as Arabic, Hindi and so on) as I understand it, it didn't do the full job.

I think you may have to go to v2.3 or even v3 to be able to this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, the **whole** emulator? Not sure of that, but try this for making Arabic apps:

http://www.vrami.net/?p=635